# EOS Unstaking and changing keys

Tags: keys, unstake

On 16.Dec.2018 I unstaked my tokens. One day later (17.Dec.2018) I  changed the keys of my account.
Today, 21.Dec.2018, I still do not see my tokens in the unstaked balance.

It says: 'Refounding'

Could I have lost my EOS by changing keys during unstaking?

Comment: What is the name of your account? You can check the current status with something like www.bloks.io

Answer (score 2):

no you will not have lost your tokens. It takes 3 days to unstake your tokens, after that they should go from "refunding" to "available".

Things to note are:

- If you unstake again before the current unstake is finished, then the refund timer will be reset to a 3 day wait.
- Sometimes, the money is unstaked but the "refund" action to convert them to liquid EOS fails, if this happens you have to run the eosio::refund command to convert your tokens to liquid EOS.